# Remove reopen vote confirm dialog

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-reopen

I think confirmation dialogs are a bad idea. The one for casting reopen votes is completely unnecessary on top of that.

The user needs to move the mouse to click on the OK button to cast a reopen vote. This is completely unnecessary. Of course, if the dialog is removed, second thoughts about reopening can't be acted upon. The solution is to allow users to rescind reopen votes.

In short, my suggestion is:

Remove the reopen vote confirm dialog and add the ability to rescind reopen votes.

Comment: How many reopen votes are you casting in a row that moving the mouse to confirm is such a huge problem?

Comment: @Wooble Why do you need the dialog anyway?

Answer (score 16):

The current implementation for rescinding close votes doesn't allow people to cast them again. This is deliberate in order to prevent a few kinds of potential abuse. Any implementation of rescinding reopen votes would likely match that, which would make it unsuitable for balancing out accidental reopen clicks. We want people to *be sure* when casting these votes.

If you really don't want to click, pressing <kbd>space</kbd> will confirm the action for you without any mouse movement needed.

Comment: What kind of abuse could result from being able to recast rescinded close votes?